# ファイルを読み込むこのRubyのコードをGoではどう書くのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby, go

ファイルを読み込んで出力

```rb
text = File.read('example.txt')
p text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たとえば [`ioutil.ReadFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile) で読み込めます。

```go
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("example.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Print(string(data))
```